# Call option with underlying following a Bachelier process

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, call

I am trying to reach a derivation/proof for how to price a call option when its underlying asset follows a Bachelier process with unknown drift term: $$dS_t=...dt+\sigma dW_t$$

but zero interest rate: $r = 0$.

I try to apply the methods described here:   [Bachelier model call option pricing formula](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32863/bachelier-model-call-option-pricing-formula) but I need $r=0$

So I wonder: how will my proces look like when finding the **arbitrage free** price for the call? Will it *necessarily* be $dS_t=r S_tdt+\sigma dW_t$ (in this case no drift at all)?

In other words: how to find the right risk neutral measure and use it to derive a call option price at time $t<T$ for $T$ being expiration day of the call?

Comment: I hope my question is clear

Comment: Then simply take the results from the question you link to and input value $0$ to $r$. What is the issue?

Comment: More specifically, to replace $\frac{1}{2r}\left(e^{2r(T-t)}-1\right)$ by $(T-t)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "*how to find the right risk neutral measure* [...]*?*"

Specifically addressing this question, let us work on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ filtered with $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$. We assume that the asset process under the physical measure $\mathbb{P}$ is:
$$\text{d}S_t=\alpha(t,S_t)\text{d}t+\sigma\text{d}W_t$$

where $\alpha(t,S_t)$ is an appropriate$^{*}$ process adapted to the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$.

We know that under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$ the discounted asset price $X_t$ is a martingale. Applying Itô's lemma to $X_t=D_tS_t$, where $D_t =D(0,t)$ is the discount factor from $t$ to $0$:
$$\begin{align}
\text{d}X_t &= -rD_tS_t\text{d}t+D_t\text{d}S_t
\\[3pt]
& = -rD_tS_t\text{d}t+D_t\alpha(t,S_t)\text{d}t+\sigma D_t\text{d}W_t
\\[3pt]
& = (\alpha(t,S_t)-rS_t)D_t\text{d}t+\sigma D_t\text{d}W_t \quad\quad\quad \text{Eq. 1}
\end{align}$$

Thus we need to change the drift of $S_t$ from $\alpha(t,S_t)$ to $rS_t$. Now let us define the following process:
$$ \tilde{W}_t=W_t+\int_0^t\frac{\alpha(t,S_t)-rS_t}{\sigma}\text{d}t$$

The process $\tilde{W}_t$ is a Brownian Motion under the risk-neutral measure $\mathbb{Q}$ defined by the [Doléans-Dade exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dol%C3%A9ans-Dade_exponential) of the adapted process $f(t)=(\alpha(t,S_t)-rS_t)/\sigma$. Then we can make the change of measure$^{\text{*}}$:
$$\begin{align}
\text{d}S_t & = \alpha(t,S_t)\text{d}t+\sigma\text{d}W_t
\\[3pt]
& = \alpha(t,S_t)\text{d}t+\sigma\left(\text{d}\tilde{W}_t-\frac{\alpha(t,S_t)-rS_t}{\sigma}\text{d}t\right)
\\[3pt]
& = rS_t\text{d}t+\sigma\text{d}\tilde{W}_t 
\end{align}$$

You can then pursue from this last equation in a similar manner as in [Bachelier model call option pricing formula](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/32863/bachelier-model-call-option-pricing-formula) but replacing $r$ by $0$ which should simplify things:

$$ S_t=S_0+\sigma\tilde{W}_t \ \sim \ \mathcal{N}(S_0,\sigma^2t)$$

**[Edit:** why does $\text{Eq. 1}$ imply that the drift of the asset needs to be $rS_t\text{d}t$ under measure $\mathbb{Q}$? We know from risk-neutral theory that the price of a derivative is the expectation of its payoff under measure $\mathbb{Q}$ (see e.g. Proposition 2.9 from $[1]$); we therefore need the distribution of the asset under the risk-neutral measure; we also know that the discounted price of the asset, $X_t=D_tS_t$, is a martingale under $\mathbb{Q}$ (see e.g. Proposition 2.8 from $[1]$). On the other hand, (local) martingales can be characterised as a process without drift, i.e. for a martingale $M_t$:
$$M_t=\sigma(t,M_t)\text{d}W_t$$
for some adapted process $\sigma(t,M_t)$, which can be a constant $\sigma$. Thus given $\text{Eq. 1}$, which gives the SDE of $X_t$, *in order to make the discounted asset a (local) martingale we need to cancel its drift under $\mathbb{Q}$ by making the drift of the asset $S_t$ to be equal to $rS_t\text{d}t$ under that same measure*. In practice, we always work with local martingales that are also martingales hence we do not bother to make all the technical checks. See the technical note from my answer to "[Why discounted derivative price is a martingale?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/34700/why-discounted-derivative-price-is-a-martingale/34705#34705)" for more details.**]**

$\text{*:}$ we would need to check [Novikov's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov%27s_condition) to ensure the change of measure is legit, we assume process $\alpha(t,S_t)$ is such that the condition is fulfilled.

**References**

$[1] $ Harrison, M. and Pliska, S. (1980). "Martingales and Stochastic Integrals in the Theory of Continuous Trading", Stochastic Process and their Applications 11, 215-260, North-Holland Publishing Company.

Comment: Actually I knew most of your (really good) answer. At some point u write:"we need to change the drift to rSdt". This is where I struggle. Maybe because I haven't understood Risk Neutral theory totally. Can you add a couple of word for WHY we need to change the drift to exactly " $rS_t dt$"

Comment: @Sanjay I updated my answer.

Comment: Where did $r$ come from in $Eq. 1$? Are you assuming that $D_t = \exp(-rt)$?

Comment: Indeed @Confounded.